# How to change tensorflow version using R runtime in colab?

Tags: r, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

In Python runtime of colab it is possible to run the command `%tensorflow_version 1.x` to change the tensorflow version. Is it possible to do the same using R runtime?

Answer (score 1):

R can use any python installation you point it at. If you're interested in running an older version of tensorflow, you can do:

```
tensorflow::install_tensorflow(method = "conda", version = "1", envname = "tf-v1")
```

Then to use it:

```
library(tensorflow)
use_condaenv("tf-v1", required=TRUE)
tf$abs(1) # will return a TF v1 style (non-eager) Tensor
```